# LIBLINEAR/LIBSVM "Wrong input format at line 1"

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm

Hi i need help with my input file: checkdata.py return with "No errors" but still something is wrong. My first line looks like:

```
+1 1:-1 2:-1 3:0.737705 4:1 5:0.737705 6:-0.959596 7:-0.757576 9:0.6875 10:0.487179 11:-0.6 12:-1 13:-0.27907 14:0.171717 15:0.777778 15:0.777778 16:-1 17:-0.463984 18:1 19:-1 20:-1 21:-0.75 22:-0.75 23:-0.75 24:-0.75 25:-0.75 26:-0.75 27:-0.75 28:-0.75 29:-0.75 30:-0.75 31:-0.75 32:-0.75 33:-1 34:-0.75 35:-0.75 36:-0.75 37:-0.75 38:-1 39:-0.75 40:-1 41:0.75 42:-1 43:1 44:1 45:1 46:1 47:1 49:1 50:1 51:1
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: how many lines does your file have?

Comment: I think this has been answered well enough, definitely the vector point 15 appearing twice. But, just for some extra info, I get the same error for vector points that aren't in the correct numerical order, so my first line looked like this: "-1 1:0.0374813 2:0.402085 1995:0.0022779 764:0.1 780:0.1 1134:0.0178571 44:0.0454545 836:0.0294118 9:0.025641 2025:0.00364964 24:0.00662252 149:0.166667 1290:0.2 2140:0.142857 2199:0.5 2181:0.0133333 645:0.00490196 766:0.2 2158:0.0526316 " and LIBSVM apparently wasn't happy with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The label 15 appears twice - checkdata.py really should be checking this, it cost me 2 hours.